# What is the correct way to play a playable copy of a track in Spotfy API?

Tags: spotify

Up until now, I have been using the playable property of a track to check whether a track is playable for the current user or not.

I have encountered a weird situation with this approach recently. Even though the track seems to be playable and available, when I try to play the track, I get an error message from Spotify stating that the album is not playable in my region. When I go and check the album of that track, it is indeed listed as unplayable, however, a playable copy of the track exists in Spotify, I can search for the track and play it.

The following text is from the api docs:

> If the resource used to construct the track isn't readily available for playback, Spotify         will automatically try to find another (equivalent) playable copy of the track.

This implies that the copy of the track that is constructed with my uri is unplayable, but the api is able to find a playable copy of this track automatically. I thought that the process works just like this while trying to play a track, i.e. finding a playable copy of the track and playing it, but it doesn't seem to be working that way. How can I play a playable copy of the track?

Comment: I'd say you've found a bug.  Wish there was a way to report bugs with the API, but there isn't AFAIK.  I have seen people get ahold of Spotify devs in IRC and get them to enter bugs internally.  For a workaround, all I can think of is to do a search for the track and try to find other copies.